# Launch a console at startup

Tags: bash, node.js

**Hello everyone !**

I want to execute a script and be able to see the console. 
That's what I wrote in rc.local

```
sudo bash -c '/home/pi/Desktop/Start_Bot-Discord.sh > /home/pi/Desktop/start1.log' &
```

And that is the content of "Start_Bot-Discord.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi/Bot-Discord
nodemon --inspect index.js
```

The logs tell me that the script was launch and is executing but there is no console..
How to I make it appear ?

Note that when I execute the command of the rc.local or the command of the .sh in a console that I manually launch, it's working...

*Thanks for reading. If you see anything that can be improve (even the question), let me know! And the same for questions or/and remarks, let me know !*

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks ! I will test and come back to tell the result

Answer (score -1):

As @Ingo said, "We have seen many problems here on this site using it(`/etc/rc.local`)."
The solution is to use [**systemmd**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md) or [**crontab**](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/auto-run-python-programs-on-the-raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score -1):

rc.local is run before the desktop is loaded.
systemd is a great option as it lets you tie into all sorts of events.
I don't recommend crontab for anything other than periodic runs.

I prefer to just put graphical on-login type stuff into
/home/pi/.bashrc

If you want the terminal to stick around, consider adding a line to read user input at the end.

Comment: **It's not that "rc.local is run before the desktop is loaded"**.  Even if it runs *after*, it is a system background service, and does not have a desktop to use.  `.bashrc` is  pretty bad idea as it runs *everytime you open an interactive shell*.   To run stuff on the desktop at start, you need to use the autostart feature of the desktop environment.